# ubuntu 22.04 HDMI dual screen sound drops out while moving mouse

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

This problem has been experienced since 18 if not earlier. I've had it through several new computers with clean installations. HDMI audio drops out for a moment when I move the mouse or any activity like browsing a directory, using Firefox, etc. Note, previously on 18 and earlier sound was fine while using analog output. Ubuntu 22.04, NVIDIA, Intel i9-3.6G 64Gig, 2T SSD

Solution: NVIDIA drivers not up to the task. Enabled motherboard embedded video, removed NVIDIA board. Problem solved.

Comment: My apologies, I have used this on a HP Z-Book i7/nvidia with 20.04 and have this problem. I have it on my PC and have changed cables and displays. I have done considerable hardware troubleshooting prior to posting. I have tried this both through two different home theater systems, and without. I just didn't want to bore everyone with a huge list of what I've eliminated.

Comment: Always include *all relevant details and research*. Otherwise you're asking for help from people who know less about the problem than you do! Better to bore than to waste time on something you already did. Please edit your question and include the details of your attempts and what you've learned. Moving on from that, I can only imagine two situations that could cause what you described. Either your system is over taxed on resources (very easy to test with a resource monitor) or the problem is physical in nature, like EM interference, crossed wires, dirty ports, etc.

Comment: For example I've seen these kinds of issues occur when you have components sharing the same power source and there is a component or components that are not well shielded either due to design or fault.

Comment: You refer to 18 in the question. The only version of Ubuntu using that as a version is Ubuntu Core. Are you running Ubuntu Core if not please use an actual version info.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: A downgrade from NVidia drivers 530 to 515 solved the problem for me.**

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 23.04. Sound disappears when directed to any of the 2 displays connected through DisplayPort with NVidia 1080 Ti.

The issue appeared after the upgrade to Lunar Lobster (23.04) from 22.10.